# Why is the velocity of fluid on top a hydrofoil higher than that on the bottom? What keeps enlarging the difference in these 2 velocities?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to learn how hydrofoil works. A big part of it is Bernoulli's principles.

I found this [article](http://web.mit.edu/2.972/www/reports/hydrofoil/hydrofoil.html) on MIT website.

There are two explanation for how it works:

1. The conservation of linear momentum or Newton's third law.If water is pushed down, the water pushes back on the hydrofoil. 
   [image]

For the change for momentum of water, their is a equal but opposite change in momentum of the hydrofoil, directed upward.

2. Bernoulli'principles: $$P_o=P+1/2dv^2+dgy$$

$P_o$ is called the stagnation of pressure and is a constant. P is pressure. d is density. v is velocity of fluid. and g is gravitational acceleration. So if v increases on top, the top pressure will decreases, and as v of fluid decreases on the bottom, the pressure with increase. The hydrofoil then starts to rise when the bottom pressure overcomes the top pressure. It rises till there is no water on top.

**QUESTION**

1. Why the velocity of fluid on top is greater than that of the fluid on bottom? The link says "this is due in part to viscous effects which lead to formation of vertices at the end of foil." But I am not sure what those "effect" and "vertices" are.

   2. What keeps the top velocity increasing, and the bottom velocity decreasing?
      I guess it's this enlarging difference in velocities that produces larger and larger pressure difference, and thus larger net force.

Comment: Poor Bernoulli has been so abused for centuries on this problem. Conservation of momentum means that some amount of water has to have a downward momentum after the hydrofoil passes over it and that is all it means. How that happens can't be (and has not been successfully) explained with energy conservation that does _not_ take the vertical movement of the water underneath the device into account.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I love the "Poor Bernoulli" :) Doeser: look [*here.*](https://www.av8n.com/how/)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, am kinda confused about why are airplane wings even needed. Commercial planes have one engines attached to each wing. The engines produce thrust, and along can push the plane skyward. Are the wings just used for taking off, where engines are blowing horizontally, with no upward component?

Comment: Make yourself a paper airplane. Make sure it's got a little bit of weight in the front, like a paper clip. Then throw it - it should follow a long horizontal path, that descends gradually (if it doesn't turn much). So the wings hold it up (nothing else does). The reason it descends is because, if it didn't, it would slow down (by drag), so less lift, so it would come down. If you have a way of giving it a little push, that would have the opposite effect, making it rise. The little push is not enough to lift the airplane, only enough to overcome the drag ...

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, if the wings are completely horizontal, and you throw it horizontally, the path would be horizontal and slowing descending because that paper clip?

Comment: ... That's what airplane engines do. They don't have nearly enough push to lift the airplane straight up (unless they are an F-whatever). Every airplane is always *gliding*, supported by its wings. If it has no push (like engine out), it glides down, gradually. If it has lots of push (full power) it glides up (climbing). In fact, very aerodynamic airplanes, with smooth surfaces, have a big problem. *They can't get down.* To get them down they have to put drag-inducing air brakes, wheels, flaps, laundry, out into the wind. That's called a *dirty* configuration.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, i know you are saying wings are useful because it provide air drag so plane can stay afloat a little longer. But the thing that concerns me is how the way wings are shaped help the plane ascend and descend.

Comment: Read what I wrote, please. The shape doesn't matter that much. BTW, the reason you put the paper clip is not to make drag. It is to make sure that if it slows down, it heads down. Otherwise you get a up-down-up-down scalloped flight.

Comment: Are air break basically air foil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40626/discussion-between-mike-dunlavey-and-doeser).

Comment: @CuriousOne, but even the water beneath the foil is flowing downward. That still means the water had to push the foil back up. So either with the conservation of momentum, the foil has go up.

Comment: @Doeser: The point is that the conventional explanation of why there is lift is wrong. Look at the drawing in the post, it doesn't show any momentum transfer to the water.

Comment: @CuriousOne, so both Newton's third law/conservation of momentum, OR Bernoulli equation can be used, right? I heard some people say Bernoulli is more "practical".

Comment: @Doeser: You can use whatever you want, but as long as it doesn't include the air that moves downwards behind the plane, it's flat out not the reason why you get lift. :-)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, what is "first order"? The article says Bernoulli is only valid to first order (P close to ambient, p to ambient density). Is first order related to ambient?

Comment: @Doeser: What "first order" means is sticking to low velocities. When you get up around the speed of sound, you have to throw more terms into the equations. Now, did you look at the *av8n* link? It's very good. It really does answer your questions.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, it does talk about circulation and obstacle effect. But can you point to the place? Like a section number? Sounds like a Venturi effect?

Comment: @Doeser: Here's how wings work: https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html. You can understand about going up and down with power here: https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/energy.html#sec-controls-energy. Now please, ***read it***.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, what generates circulation in nature? In the barn door example in 3.12, the air flow near the surface of the door backward the flow of air blowing at the wing. There are man made circulation, but what happen in nature?